# Is ham still good

Tags: ham

Whole pre-cooked ham served on Christmas Day.  Been meaning to make pea soup with bones but it now Jan. 10.  The ham still smells fine, not slimmey. Should I use it?

Comment: We can't really answer this unless you tell us how it's been stored. Was it in the freezer? Fridge?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your ham was cured. Every method of processing food -- salting, smoking, pickling, fermenting, drying, chilling, and so on -- were originally ways to stop the food from spoiling and becoming toxic. With modern refrigeration, we rely less on the traditional methods to keep food safe to eat, and more to give it flavour and character.

Originally, a cured and smoked ham could be relied on to to last through much of the winter, but it would be very strongly flavoured with sodium and potassium. Recently, manufacturers expect their customers to be able to refrigerate their food and to require a lower sodium content.

If you ask the manufacturer they will tell you to throw your ham away. It may gain them another sale, and it removes the risk of a court case if you become ill. But you should trust your senses of smell and taste. While there may be no guarantees, the palate is very sensitive to food that is so stale as to be toxic. Even modern bacon, which generally contains more salt than ham, may often be left wrapped at room temperature for weeks or months without degrading to the point of being a health risk.

In summary, you should be fine as long as long as you don't sense a problem, especially if the meat has been refrigerated below 5 Celsius for only a few days. If you want absolute guarantees, then throw your meat away and become a vegetarian.